# How to make Total Commander move to folder beginning with "X" when pressing Alt+"X"?

Tags: total-commander

Is it possible to make Total Commander move to folder beginning with `X` when pressing `Alt+X` (where X could be any letter)? Imho this behaviour is common for all console gui file commanders like nc, vc, dn, far, mc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under *Configuration - Quick Search*, choose *Alt+Letters* or *Letters - with search dialog*.